# Change css class on child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to remove CSS class from my elements:

```
$('.input-group-addon').child($('.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').removeClass());
```

Now on same action immediately I remove that class I want to add `myClass` for example so I tried:

```
$('.input-group-addon').child().addClass('myClass');
```

But this doesn't work, my element stays with `class=""` instead of `class="myClass"`.

Comment: because you remove the class right?how can you add to a classless element?

Comment: Add your html code here

Comment: Replace .child() with .children(). There is no .child() method in jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `children()` at all:

```
$('.input-group-addon > .glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').removeClass();
```

Add class back to all direct ancestors:

```
$('.input-group-addon > *').addClass('myClass');
```

Answer (score 1):

`.child()` is not a jQuery function replace it by `.children()` :

```
$('.input-group-addon').children().removeClass();
$('.input-group-addon').children().addClass('myClass');
```

Or without `children()` method :

```
$('.input-group-addon .glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').removeClass();
$('.input-group-addon .glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').addClass('myClass');
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the class you want to remove..

```
$('.input-group-addon').child($('.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').removeClass("className"));
```

Currently, this

```
$('.input-group-addon').child($('.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar').removeClass());
```

removes everything.